# Pass model object to mongoose request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I would like to save an object from one schema to the array in another one. What I have is User schema and Events schema. User schema has, for example, a property "joined" which is array. When making put request, meeting should be pushed to "joined" array.

At the moment I have this code on clientside:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events">    
...
    <button ng-click="joinEvent(event)">Join</button>
</div>


$scope.joinEvent = function(event){

    $http.put('/join', event)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        })
};
```

and this this in express.js routes:

```
app.put('/join', function (req, res){
        var user = req.user; // logged in user
        var id = req.user._id;
        var update = { $addToSet: {joined: req.event} };

        User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {upsert: true}, function (err, user) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("joined");
                    //return all users from db
                    User.find(function(err, users) {
                        if (err)
                            res.send(err)
                        res.json(users);
                    });
                } else {
                    if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                        res.statusCode = 400;
                        res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
                    } else {
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
                    }
                    console.log('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
                }
         });
    });
```

After all, I see 'null' in user.joined. What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to get the event name is wrong. 
In your code, `req.event == null` . That's why you see null in 'user.joined'.

In the client - event property should look like this:
`event = {eventName: "someEventName"}`

In the server - you reach to event name like this:

```
var update = { $addToSet: {joined: req.body.eventName} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yarden for pushing me into the right direction. I made it in other way by passing event id on clientside and making Event.findById query before looking for user. That worked.